# Code Coverage for JSON Deserialize Typed

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, deserialize, type

I am having trouble getting test code coverage for a JSON response that I'm deserializing typed, and am not exactly sure how to properly test. Any advice would be appreciated!

Here is the code I'm trying to cover:

```
public class jsonObject {

    @auraEnabled
    public Content content;
    @auraEnabled
    public String retrievalDate;
    
    public class Content {
        @auraEnabled
        public Links x_links; // in json: _links
        @auraEnabled
        public Carrier carrier;
    }
    
    public class CarrierOperation {
        @auraEnabled
        public String carrierOperationCode;
        @auraEnabled
        public String carrierOperationDesc;
    }
    
    public class CensusTypeId {
        @auraEnabled
        public String censusType;
        @auraEnabled
        public String censusTypeDesc;
        @auraEnabled
        public Integer censusTypeId;
    }
    
    public class Carrier {
        @auraEnabled
        public String allowedToOperate;
        @auraEnabled
        public CarrierOperation carrierOperation;
        @auraEnabled
        public CensusTypeId censusTypeId;
        @auraEnabled
        public String ein;
        @auraEnabled
        public String legalName;
        @auraEnabled
        public String phyCity;
        @auraEnabled
        public String phyCountry;
        @auraEnabled
        public String phyState;
        @auraEnabled
        public String phyStreet;
        @auraEnabled
        public String phyZipcode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that this is a class with public inner classes and attributes, you should be able to attain coverage by instantiating the class manually without using `JSON.deserialize`.

Comment: As there is no actual logic in your class (nor in the inner classes), there's not really anything to gain code coverage for here. At most, you'd just need to have a test that instantiates a `JsonObject` instance, and populates some of the member variables. I suspect that having a single line "covered" here will be enough to satisfy Salesforce.

Comment: @JesseWheeler or DerekF - Could you elaborate on instantiating the member variables? I have tried populating 'content' variables, but am getting a null pointer exception when trying to run my tests after populating variables

Comment: It's not "instantiating the member variables", it's "get an instance of your class" and then "set class variable(s)". E.g. `jsonObject myInstance = new jsonObject();` followed by `myInstance.retrievalDate = Date.today();` and/or `myInstance.content = new jsonObject.Content();`. You'll need to [edit] your question to show us your test class (and/or whatever is giving you the Null Pointer Exception).